# Can't print ñ in an octave plot

Tags: octave

I need to generate a graph (I'm using octave, to do so) that has an ñ character and I can't seem to be able to do that.

This is what I've tried

```
xlabel('A\~no','interpreter','tex')
```

However this prints the \ and the ~ just like in the parameter.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not on the list of supported TeX characters as listed on the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Use-of-the-interpreter-Property.html) (see Table 15.1).

However, it's perfectly fine to use the ñ directly. The most simple solution `xlabel ("Año")` works fine on my system (Octave 3.8.0 with fltk as graphics toolkit).

Comment: I was using gnu plot as the graphics toolkit because of the facilities to print to a specfic font. When I changed to fltk the font change was ignored. Anyways, both methods gave me the exact same result which is: missing glyph for character '�'. And the ñ does not appear. I am using octave 3.6.4 from debian repository so util it is updated changing versions to try this out is not really an option. Any other ideas? Thank you, for your answer anyways.

Comment: @user792589 Of course it is. I have version 3.8.0 because I built it myself from source. Octave provides online instructions for it. In addition, a PPA is also provided. See [Octave for Debian systems](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems)

Comment: For me Hungarian accented characters work quite well on Linux, but those, who use octave on Windows can't even insert accented characters into the file with the octave GUI. (At least from keyboard, I did not tried copy pasting.) However accented characters like (á, é, ö...) does not appears well on saved figures. (Ubuntu 14.04, octave 4.0.2 vs Windows 8 and 10 octave 4.0.3)

Comment: @ArpadHorvath I'm running Octave on Linux, and can insert those characters with and without the GUI. I can also get them displayed on the axis labels no problem. But indeed, once the figure is saved, the accented characters are no longer correct.